# prevent same task in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react' import { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
        { id: 1, text: 'Task1' }, { id: 2, text: 'Task2' }, { id: 3, text: 'Task3' }
    ])
    const showTasks = tasks.map((task) => <h2>{task.text}<button onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)}>X</button></h2>)

    const onDelete = (id) => {
        setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id))
    }

    const [text, setText] = useState('')

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (!text || tasks > text || text === setTasks) {
            alert('Problem');
            return
        }
        addTask({ text })
        setText('')
    }

    const addTask = (task) => {
        const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
        const newTask = { id, ...task };
        setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{showTasks}</div>

            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input type='text' value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
                <input type='submit' value='Save Task' />
            </form>

        </div>
    ) }

export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the condition to avoid duplicates in the `onSubmit` function.

```
!text || tasks.some((item) => item.text === text)
```

```js
const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, text: "Task1" },
    { id: 2, text: "Task2" },
    { id: 3, text: "Task3" }
  ]);
  const showTasks = tasks.map((task) => (
    <h2 key={task.id}>
      {task.text}
      <button onClick={() => onDelete(task.id)}>X</button>
    </h2>
  ));

  const onDelete = (id) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!text || tasks.some((item) => item.text === text)) {
      alert("Duplicate");
      return;
    }
    addTask({ text });
    setText("");
  };

  const addTask = (task) => {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000) + 1;
    const newTask = { id, ...task };
    setTasks([...tasks, newTask]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{showTasks}</div>

      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={text}
          onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Save Task" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: arguably `some()` is more appropriate than `find()` since it returns a boolean.